# Unable to show any output in a JTable using MySql data

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

In my code, I am not seeing any output in the Jtable.

In NetBeans, I have a JTable inside a JFrame, then i created a mysql database connection.

In MYSQL i created a table as StudentMaster and I'm inserting the data from it inside the JTable. when i select the data in JTable, it's not showing any output and there is no error neither.

Please help me.

```
public class dbtable extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    ResultSet result=null;
    Connection conn=null;
      Statement st=null;

    public dbtable() {
        initconn();
        initComponents();
    }
     public Connection initconn(){
    try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project", "root", "root");
            st = conn.createStatement();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    return conn;
    }
    public void tab(){
        try {
            DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();

            st=conn.createStatement();
                String query="Select * from StudentMaster";
                result=st.executeQuery(query);
                int i=0;
                while(result.next())
                {
                    String id=result.getString("StudId");
                    System.out.println(id);
                    String no=result.getString("StudNo");
                    String name=result.getString("StudName");
                    System.out.println(name);
                    String stcls=result.getString("StudClass");
                    String m1=result.getString("StudMrk1");
                    String m2=result.getString("StudMrk2");
                    String tot=result.getString("StudTot");
                    String res=result.getString("StudRes");

                    model.addRow(new Object[]{id,no,name,stcls,m1,m2,tot,res});
                }
                jTable1.setModel(model);
                result.close();
                 st.close();
                 conn.close();
            }
           catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }

    }

     /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        CmdA = new javax.swing.JButton();
        CmdE = new javax.swing.JButton();
        CmdD = new javax.swing.JButton();
        CmdX = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 10));

        jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, java.awt.Color.darkGray));

        jPanel2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, java.awt.Color.darkGray));

        CmdA.setText("+");
        CmdA.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                CmdAActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        CmdE.setText("E");

        CmdD.setText("-");
        CmdD.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                CmdDActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        CmdX.setMnemonic('Q');
        CmdX.setText("Q");
        CmdX.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                CmdXActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(24, 24, 24)
                .addComponent(CmdA, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 60, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(CmdE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 60, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(CmdD, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 60, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(CmdX, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 60, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(25, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jPanel2Layout.linkSize(javax.swing.SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, new java.awt.Component[] {CmdA, CmdD, CmdE, CmdX});

        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE, false)
                    .addComponent(CmdE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 70, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(CmdA, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 70, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(CmdD, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 70, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(CmdX, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 70, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(47, 47, 47))
        );

        jPanel2Layout.linkSize(javax.swing.SwingConstants.VERTICAL, new java.awt.Component[] {CmdA, CmdD, CmdE, CmdX});

        jPanel3.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, java.awt.Color.darkGray));

        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "ID", "Reg_No", "Name", "Class", "Subj 1", "Subj 2", "Total", "Result"
            }
        ) {
            Class[] types = new Class [] {
                java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.Integer.class
            };
            boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
                false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false
            };

            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return types [columnIndex];
            }

            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                return canEdit [columnIndex];
            }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setResizable(false);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(25);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setResizable(false);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(25);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setResizable(false);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(250);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setResizable(false);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(150);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setResizable(false);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(25);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setResizable(false);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setPreferredWidth(25);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setResizable(false);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setPreferredWidth(25);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setResizable(false);
        jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setPreferredWidth(25);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
        jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
        jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 865, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 865, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 119, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 108, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(546, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 100, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(543, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(209, 209, 209)
                    .addComponent(jPanel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 95, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(350, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void CmdXActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     

    }                                    

    private void CmdDActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     

    }                                    

    private void CmdAActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     

    }                                    

    /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               new dbtable().tab();
                new dbtable().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton CmdA;
    private javax.swing.JButton CmdD;
    private javax.swing.JButton CmdE;
    private javax.swing.JButton CmdX;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    // End of variables declaration

}
```

Comment: PLEASE LEARN java naming conventions and stick to them ... NOW

Comment: Can you update a table using data that is *not* coming from a DB?  If not, the DB is irrelevant.  If so, it is better to factor the table out of the problem and concentrate on the DB.  Either way, shorter code focused more on the actual problem, as well as sticking to common Java nomenclature, might provide some progress.

Answer (score 3):

Generated code is difficult to read so I would try to avoid it, especially if you're new to Swing or you will have a lot of code that you can't read and don't understand.

That being said, your main contains something smelly:

```
 new dbtable().tab();
 new dbtable().setVisible(true);
```

So, you're creating 2 instances of your Frame; the first one is populated with mysql data but never made visible. The second one is not populated but made visible => you'll see 1 frame which is not populated.

Try:

```
 dbtable dbt = new dbtable();
 dbt.tab()
 dbt.setVisible(true);
```

BTW: try to respect java naming conventions:  http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm

Comment: this is correct. You are creating two tables and you are showing the empty one.